# Jenkinsfile load groovy file parameter in key and value format in environment variable in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

besically my groovy file jenkins-build-paramters.groovy is as below

```
Cotaining_WAR_Deployment='true'
Cotaining_JAR_Deployment='false'
```

Below is my environment variable

```
    environment {
        Cotaining_WAR_Deployment= "true"    
        Cotaining_JAR_Deployment= "false"
    }
```

My question how can i load the build paramters based on respective value. For instance, in environment Cotaining_WAR_Deployment should take from the groovy file value

Comment: Just to clarify: you want your pipeline to read a groovy file which contains variables and those should be accessible as environment variables in the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [load step][1] to load a groovy script.

Modify your `jenkins-build-paramters.groovy` as follows:

```
Cotaining_WAR_Deployment='true'
Cotaining_JAR_Deployment='false'

return this
```

Then you can load it like so:

```
stage('load params'){
    script {
        def parameters = load "${workspace}/jenkins-build-paramters.groovy"
        Cotaining_WAR_Deployment = parameters.Cotaining_WAR_Deployment
        Cotaining_JAR_Deployment = parameters.Cotaining_JAR_Deployment
    }
}
```

By the way, you don't need to store boolean variables as string (`"true"`) you can use them as booleans as well (`true`)
[1]: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script

Comment: I wish to use it in environment rather than steps. Environment for individual stage. My script is as below stage -> environment -> when -> steps

Comment: I don't think that is possible. But you can limit the scope of the variables to the current stage

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jenkins-build-paramters.groovy with the following content:

```
env.Cotaining_WAR_Deployment='true'
env.Cotaining_JAR_Deployment='false'
```

Then load this wile with the following step:

```
pipeline {
  <...>
  stages {
    stage('Checkout repo') {
      steps {
        load 'jenkins-build-paramters.groovy'
        echo "${env.Cotaining_WAR_Deployment}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It should be accessible same as other environment variables set with

```
environment {
  Cotaining_WAR_Deployment= "true"    
  Cotaining_JAR_Deployment= "false"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Different alternative you load it from properties file instead of Groovy:

`props = readProperties(file: FilePath)`

and then read all the values from `props`. The main advantage of using [readProperties](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) instead of loading from a Groovy file for me, was I can loop through all the fetched key-value pairs easily and even declare them as environment variables if I want. I couldn't find any way to do same with groovy file

`readProperties(file: FilePath).each {key, value -> env[key] = value }`